# How to deploy an npm project to Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm, socket.io, vue-cli

I currently have an npm project built with vue-cli and socket.io server.

This is how my project is structured:

`Project/
|--node_server/
|  |--server.js
|--src/
|  |--main.js
|  |--App.vue
|  |--other .vue files and folders`

I do not know how to deploy this app on Heroku because I will need to run two scripts while deploying that is `node server.js` (in the node_server folder) and `npm run build` or `npm run dev` (in the root folder).

What are the steps on how to deploy it successfully? Heroku takes my project from github whenever I push and builds it automatically. I have tried deploying but it ends up with an error page.

Comment: you can specify `start` script in your package.json like `node server.js & npm run build`

Comment: Please can you add the steps? How to specify two scripts.

Comment: I have just posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you need to build the front-end with `build` script first, and then you need to run nodejs server with `start` script which is `node server.js`.

```
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gulp or something idk"
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "start": "node node_server/server.js",
  },
  ...
```

But if you need to run these two scripts at the same time you can achieve this with something like that:

```
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gulp or something idk"
    "start": "npm run build & node node_server/server.js",
  },
  ...
```

I hope it would be helpful.

For an example, you can take a look at the package.json of one of my project: https://github.com/hisener/pirate-radio/blob/master/package.json

For more information, please refer https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts

Comment: Thanks very much please add another **&** to the second code snippet. I tried editing but it did not work

Comment: @KofiMokome You would use & if you want both commands to run simultaneously. && means run commands sequentially.

Comment: Thanks @hisener once again. Your solution worked perfectly but I realised that the node server and socket server are trying to use the same port and it causes an error. Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: I fixed the problem. Decided to use one server instead of two.